# Xamarin android SendBroadcast from IntentService not received by Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

As in title broadcast from IntentService is not received.
Here's how I have it set up:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { MyService.ToUploadCountNotification })]
public class MyService : IntentService
{
    public const string ToUploadCountNotification = "MyService.ToUploadCountNotification";
    public const string ToUploadCount = "MyService.ToUploadCount";

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        while (Count > 0)
        {
            var uploadCount = new Intent();
            uploadCount.SetAction(ToUploadCountNotification);
            uploadCount.PutExtra(ToUploadCount, localHarryys.Count);
            Log.Debug("Sync service", "sending broadcast");
            SendBroadcast(intent, null);
        }
    }
}

public class MyServiceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        Toast.MakeText(context,
                       string.Format("Uploading...({0})", intent.Extras.GetInt(MyService.ToUploadCount)),
                       ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

In activity I register receiver:

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(_receiver, new IntentFilter(MyHarryysSyncService.ToUploadCountNotification));
        Log.Debug("Browse", "Receiver registered");
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        UnregisterReceiver(_receiver);
        Log.Debug("Browse", "Receiver unregistered");
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(MyService)));
        }
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

In my research all I could find was

- make sure that you register it correctly in activity - **I believe I do** I've also put it in OnCreate/OnDestroy see below
- activity might not be visible/active at the time service sends broadcast - From debug window I get correct order of messages *Receiver registered* / *sending broadcast* so I'm assuming that activity is active and receiver registered.

I've tested couple more things.

After line `StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(MyService)))` 
I've put `SendBroadcast(new Intent(MyService.ToUploadCountNotification), null);`
that didn't work till I've move registration to OnCreate/OnDestroy. Unfortunatelly broadcast from service was still not received

I've registered receiver in *androidmanifest.xml* that works as well but I wanted to have it registered dynamically by activity as there might be different behaviour depending on active activity.

So my question is what else am I doing wrong there. What else can I check.

Comment: I think you are missing [BroadcastReceiver] attribute on your receiver

Comment: I though that is only to register receiver in androidmanifest.xml file which mean that it will be statically registered. And if I register it by RegisterReciever I don't have to or even I shouldn't do that.