# Android AlarmManager Alarm to start Service

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

Working in VisualStudio with Xamarin and only have < 2 weeks experience with Android.

I have an IntentService class that I want to use an alarm to start. This beauty of IntentService is threading and it will stop when it is finished working. I do not understand how to implement an alarm using AlarmManager. I am following [This Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) and using the ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP example.

This code is in the  MainActivity under OnCreate()

```
     AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, startTrackingService());


     alarmMgr.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,             
     trackingSetting,
     trackingSetting, intent);


     public void startTrackingService() {
     Intent i = new Intent(this, StoreLocationService.class ); //
     StartService(i);
        }
```

Right now I am getting the following errors:

- Must have a return type

  ```
  StartService(i);
  ```
- Identifier expected; class is a keyword

  ```
  Intent i = new Intent(this.StoreLocationService.class );
  ```

I hope someone can see the glaring errors. I hope that I have the right idea with the Alarm in the MainActivity that uses StartService(Intent Service) to start the service.

---

**Additional question:**  The service I want to start does a one time Location tracking event. While I want the timer/alarm to work while the screen is off for this tracking, I think that I can therefore not rely on the main activity. Wrong or right?

I have a second service which I will make later. It syncs this data to the local database

Comment: have you checked the value of trackingsetting.

Comment: yes it initialized to zero

Comment: if it is initialised to zero how will you get the alarm?

Comment: How do you know your alarm is getting set properly?

Comment: Is that valid to have the `startTrackingService()` function as the second parameter for the `Intent` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Ok, after reading up on Xamarin, it looks like this might help for the `Identifier expected; class is a keyword` error:

```
StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(StoreLocationService)));
```

References:

[Xamarin android SendBroadcast from IntentService not received by Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816980/xamarin-android-sendbroadcast-from-intentservice-not-received-by-activity)

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_2_android_services/

Edit 2:
I also just noticed that there are some differences with Xamarin with AlarmManagers `getSystemService` should be `GetSystemService`, and also it looks like you need a `PendingIntent` (this is needed for `AlarmManager` in Java as well).

General example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(StoreLocationService));
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 0, i, 0);
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
alarmMgr.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, trackingSetting, trackingSetting, pintent);
```

See this post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16111/setting-alarmmanager-to-repeat-given-a-specific-time

And this post: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7490/alarm-manager

Comment: One thing I see is that you have never done Android in C# ! Oddly enough there are some minor differences! I really appreciate your reply tho Daniel

Comment: Oh no!  Sorry about that.  Let me go back to the drawing board!

Comment: Thanks man. I went back to the documentation for PendingIntent and saw GetService(). Thank you very much for making the General Example and doing some research with me. I know that I could not have done it without you and I am quite thankful. I still am not sure how a PendingIntent uses an Intent as its third parameter and how the alarm uses the pintent parameter to eventually get the Intent of StoreLocationService.